# How to connect to Amazon Neptune by using ssh Java

Tags: java, ssh, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I've setup a ssh tunnel to allow connecting to NeptuneDB 

and now i want to use Java from local machine to connect 
to NeptuneDB by using ssh, so is there any way to do that?

Comment: This question comes up quite often and makes perfect sense to me. I have provided a detailed answer below. However, to avoid a moderator closing this question it would be good if you can add a little more information about what you had already tried per Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it’s possible. You need to add the DNS name of the Neptune cluster to your local `hosts` file and use that name in your code and when creating the SSH tunnel. Do not use `localhost` as the SSL certs will not resolve if you do. The line in your `hosts` file will be of the form:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost my.cluster-abcdefghijk.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com
```

The ssh tunnel can then be created using something like

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com  -N -L 8182:my.cluster-abcdefghijk.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182
```

In your Java code you can then build the connection something like this:

```java
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
builder.addContactPoint("my.cluster-abcdefghijk.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com");
builder.port(8182);
builder.serializer(Serializers.GRAPHBINARY_V1D0);
builder.enableSsl(true);
cluster = builder.create();
drc = DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster);
g = traversal().withRemote(drc);
```

Comment: Thanks, your code worked but i want to use spring boot to get data from neptune database. Do you have any config ? i use intelliJ IDE to code, so what do i have to add for app.properties file?

Comment: I’m glad the code worked. However, That’s really a new question. Perhaps accept the answer to this one and create a new question for Spring Boot so that people expert in that area will see it?